# I wonder if there were any grammar mistake in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar

Order which the address of it is from '深汕' and the age is under 16, that has been dispatched to the specific business-hall.

I want to describe the inner field of main subject via this part(**which the address of it is from '深汕' and the age is under 16**), and in the next part(**that has been dispatched to the specific business-hall**), I use **that** to refer to **Order**, is this correct?

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic, but if you are talking about a person, say _their_ age and address, not _its_.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It's not a sentence, for one thing (there are 2 subordinate clauses and no main verb).

Comment: Some say that when you translate from language A to B, it's better to use someone whose native tongue is B. Not a translator who claims their B abilities are tops.